# Unit Test : Assert for a List<int>, a List<DateTime> and a DateTime

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm trying to validate 3 unit test ; i've detected that they always gone wrong because of the assertion that is maybe not adapted to that type of object (or add something at the creation of the object).

Here's my code :

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestsUnitairesSaisieHeures
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestsSaisieHeures
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void NumeroSemaineTest()
        {
            //1 - Initialisation des variables
            DateTime DateTest = new DateTime(2016,11,3);
            List<int> expected = new List<int>(new int[] { 44, 45, 46, 47, 48 });
            List<int> actual;

            //2 - Appel de la méthode à tester
            actual = SaisieHeures.SaisieHeures.NumeroSemaine(DateTest);

            //3 - Vérification du résultat
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            Assert.Inconclusive("Vérifiez l\'exactitude de cette méthode de test.");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetWeekDaysOfWeekFromTest()
        {
            int weekNumberTest = 33;
            List<DateTime> expected = new List<DateTime>(new DateTime[] {new DateTime(2016,8,15),new DateTime(2016,8,16),new DateTime(2016,8,17), new DateTime(2016, 8, 18), new DateTime(2016, 8, 19), new DateTime(2016, 8, 20), new DateTime(2016, 8, 21) });
            List<DateTime> actual;

            actual = SaisieHeures.SaisieHeures.GetWeekDaysOfWeekFrom(weekNumberTest);

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            Assert.Inconclusive("Vérifiez l\'exactitude de cette méthode de test.");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void FirstDateOfWeekISO8601Test()
        {
            int yearTest = 2016;
            int weekOfYearTest = 44;
            DateTime expected = new DateTime(2016,11,1);
            DateTime actual;

            actual = SaisieHeures.SaisieHeures.FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(yearTest, weekOfYearTest);

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            Assert.Inconclusive("Vérifiez l\'exactitude de cette méthode de test.");
        }

        // Pour exécuter du code avant d'exécuter le premier test dans la classe
        [ClassInitialize()]
        public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
        {
        }

        // Pour exécuter du code après que tous les tests ont été exécutés dans une classe 
        [ClassCleanup()] public static void MyClassCleanup()
        {
        }

        // Pour exécuter du code avant d'exécuter chaque test 
        [TestInitialize()]
        public void MyTestInitialize()
        {
        }

        // Pour exécuter du code après que chaque test a été exécuté 
        [TestCleanup()]
        public void MyTestCleanup()
        {
        } 
    }
}
```

Anybody see how can i code this by adapting the assertion to my objects, add something to make it work, or anything else ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: use CollectionAssert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [CollectionAssert.AreEqual Method (ICollection, ICollection)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243763.aspx) when asserting the collections.

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

> Verifies that two specified collections are equal. The assertion fails
>   if the collections are not equal.

```
[TestMethod]
public void NumeroSemaineTest()
{
    //1 - Initialisation des variables
    DateTime DateTest = new DateTime(2016,11,3);
    List<int> expected = new List<int>(new int[] { 44, 45, 46, 47, 48 });
    List<int> actual;

    //2 - Appel de la méthode à tester
    actual = SaisieHeures.SaisieHeures.NumeroSemaine(DateTest);

    //3 - Vérification du résultat
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    Assert.Inconclusive("Vérifiez l\'exactitude de cette méthode de test.");
}
```

The test with the `DateTime` looks correct. if it is failing then that means you should check the code that it is testing to make sure it is doing what is expected.

Comment: If you want to make sure your collections have the same items in the same quantities but you don't care if they are in the same order you can use [`CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(ICollection, ICollection)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243779.aspx) instead

Comment: Noted. That is also nice to know

Comment: 2 on 3 works (the ones with the List<int> and the List<DateTime>) ; one left. The problem with the unit test with DateTime it's that, i think, it's compare two DateTime with all it's contents : the date AND the hour. I only want to conserve the date part. I have to see what to do for this last unit test. Thanks @Nkosi ;)

Comment: based on your last comment, try `Assert.AreEqual(expected.Date, actual.Date);` in the `FirstDateOfWeekISO8601Test`

Comment: That's what i did and it's perfectly work ; i've just changed the Date to 31/10/2016 which is the first day of week 44 ; i detect that i've made a mistake. My 3 unit tests works. Thanks a lot for your help @Nkosi ;)

Answer (score 1):

When comparing *collections* you should use [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx) (if you want to ensure that collections are equal by *comparing their items*):

```
[TestMethod]
public void NumeroSemaineTest()
{
    //1 - Initialisation des variables
    DateTime DateTest = new DateTime(2016,11,3);
    List<int> expected = new List<int>(new int[] { 44, 45, 46, 47, 48 });
    List<int> actual;

    //2 - Appel de la méthode à tester
    actual = SaisieHeures.SaisieHeures.NumeroSemaine(DateTest);

    //3 - Vérification du résultat
    Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual));
    Assert.Inconclusive("Vérifiez l\'exactitude de cette méthode de test.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you to for your answer @DmitryBychenko ;)